# JavaScript Uncaught TypeError - Shopping Cart Total

Tags: javascript, html

I'm finishing the project and I'm struggling with couple things:

**1 Shopping Cart in javascript**
I expected `<p class="subTotal">$ 0</p>` to update after adding, or deleting elements from the shopping cart. Instead, when I add element to the shopping cart, p.subTotal updates 2x the price of dish.

The next one is deleting elements from the shopping cart. When I do that, the console return this:

[Console screenshot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVOzD.png)

**2 Removing the object**

To remove object from the shopping cart I had to select parent of the parent of the button.
Inside the button I've put the svg icon. Somehow, when I click on svg icon, javascript code selects parent of the parent of the svg instead of the button's.

**3 Adding dishes to the shopping cart**

I've put `<a href="#" class="addToCart">` inside of `<div class="food">`.
This action results in console, showing me another error:

[Console screenshot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGiqE.png)

**If You can answer even one question I will really appreciate that.**
**I have only few hours left to finish it.**

**Code:**

```js
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready);
} else {
  ready();
}

function ready() {
  var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('trash');

  for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
    var button = removeCartItemButtons[i];
    button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem);
  }

  var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('quantity');
  for (var i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
    var input = quantityInputs[i];
    input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged);
  }

  var addToCart = document.getElementsByClassName('addToCart');
  for (var i = 0; i < addToCart.length; i++) {
    var button = addToCart[i];
    button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked);
  }
}

function removeCartItem(event) {
  var buttonClicked = event.target;
  buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
  updateCartTotal();
}

function quantityChanged(event) {
  var input = event.target;
  if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
    input.value = 1;
  }
  updateCartTotal();
}

function addToCartClicked(event) {
  var button = event.target;
  var shopItem = button.parentElement;
  var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('name')[0].innerText;
  var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('price')[0].innerText;
  var imageSrc = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('foodImg')[0].src;
  addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc);
  updateCartTotal();
}

function addItemToCart(title, price, imageSrc) {
  var product = document.createElement('div');
  product.classList.add('product');
  var basket = document.getElementsByClassName('basket')[0];

  var productContents = `
      <div class="product">
      <div class="productInfo">
          <div class="productName">
              <img src="${imageSrc}" alt="Spicy seasoned seafood noodles">
              <div>
                  <p class="productTitle">${title}</p>
                  <p class="money">${price}</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <input class="quantity" type="text" value="1">
          <p class="cash">${price}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="note">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Order Note...">
          <button class="trash"><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path
                      d="M18.8789 8.71882L18.9784 8.72017C19.3475 8.75069 19.6304 9.05716 19.65 9.42605L19.6405 9.63174L19.326 13.483L18.9961 17.2414C18.9263 17.9917 18.8638 18.6245 18.8099 19.1227C18.6225 20.8588 17.4955 21.9323 15.7966 21.9641C13.1494 22.013 10.6048 22.0125 8.13373 21.9591C6.48398 21.9244 5.37366 20.8393 5.18955 19.1297L5.0623 17.8702L4.83994 15.427L4.61216 12.7461L4.35172 9.52788C4.31935 9.11498 4.61951 8.75335 5.02215 8.72016C5.39123 8.68973 5.7183 8.94584 5.79519 9.30677L5.82511 9.60173L6.06966 12.6187L6.33669 15.7459C6.45646 17.0996 6.56034 18.1952 6.64346 18.9648C6.74838 19.939 7.26138 20.4404 8.16411 20.4593C10.6159 20.5124 13.1415 20.5129 15.7701 20.4643C16.7277 20.4464 17.2488 19.9499 17.356 18.9574L17.4827 17.7046C17.5198 17.3185 17.5594 16.8923 17.6013 16.4293L17.8686 13.3538L18.1906 9.4075C18.2204 9.02902 18.5192 8.7389 18.8789 8.71882ZM3.73139 6.98918C3.32745 6.98918 3 6.65338 3 6.23916C3 5.85945 3.27515 5.54564 3.63214 5.49597L3.73139 5.48913H6.91772C7.29636 5.48913 7.62785 5.23928 7.74642 4.87929L7.77543 4.76813L8.02304 3.50533C8.24111 2.66897 8.9492 2.07349 9.779 2.00633L9.93592 2H14.0639C14.9075 2 15.6523 2.54628 15.9391 3.39039L15.9874 3.55209L16.2243 4.76783C16.2987 5.14872 16.6025 5.4332 16.9701 5.48177L17.0821 5.48913H20.2686C20.6725 5.48913 21 5.82493 21 6.23916C21 6.61887 20.7248 6.93267 20.3679 6.98234L20.2686 6.98918H3.73139ZM14.0639 3.50006H9.93592C9.7307 3.50006 9.54829 3.62322 9.47252 3.77803L9.44682 3.84604L9.20979 5.06238C9.1808 5.21084 9.13879 5.3538 9.08512 5.49012L14.9148 5.49031C14.8813 5.40526 14.8523 5.31763 14.8282 5.22768L14.79 5.06208L14.5636 3.8928C14.5107 3.68991 14.3473 3.54138 14.1502 3.50742L14.0639 3.50006Z" />
              </svg></button>
      </div>
    </div>`;
  product.innerHTML = productContents;
  basket.append(product);
  product
    .getElementsByClassName('trash')[0]
    .addEventListener('click', removeCartItem);
  product
    .getElementsByClassName('quantity')[0]
    .addEventListener('change', quantityChanged);
}

function updateCartTotal() {
  var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('basket')[0];
  var products = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('product');
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    var product = products[i];
    var priceElement = product.getElementsByClassName('money')[0];
    var quantityElement = product.getElementsByClassName('quantity')[0];
    var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('$', ''));
    var quantity = quantityElement.value;
    total = total + price * quantity;
  }
  total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;
  document.getElementsByClassName('subTotal')[0].innerText = '$ ' + total;
}

// Date in header
var dt = new Date();
document.getElementById('datetime').innerHTML = dt.toLocaleDateString();
```

```html
<div id="foodCard">
  <div class="food">
    <a href="#" class="addToCart">
      <div class="bg">
        <img class="foodImg" src="style/img/Image 1.png" alt="Spicy seasoned seafood noodles">
        <div class="text">
          <p class="name">Spicy seasoned seafood noodles</p>
          <div>
            <p class="price">$ 2.29</p>
            <p class="availability">20 Bowls available</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="food">
    <a href="#" class="addToCart">
      <div class="bg">
        <img class="foodImg" src="style/img/Image 2.png" alt="Salted Pasta with mushroom sauce">
        <div class="text">
          <p class="name">Salted Pasta with mushroom sauce</p>
          <div>
            <p class="price">$ 2.69</p>
            <p class="availability">11 Bowls available</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="food">
    <a href="#" class="addToCart">
      <div class="bg">
        <img class="foodImg" src="style/img/Image 3.png" alt="Beef dumpling in hot and sour soup">
        <div class="text">
          <p class="name">Beef dumpling in hot and sour soup</p>
          <div>
            <p class="price">$ 2.99</p>
            <p class="availability">16 Bowls available</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="food">
    <a href="#" class="addToCart">
      <div class="bg">
        <img class="foodImg" src="style/img/Image 5.png" alt="Spicy seasoned seafood noodles">
        <div class="text">
          <p class="name">Spicy seasoned seafood noodles</p>
          <div>
            <p class="price">$ 2.29</p>
            <p class="availability">20 Bowls available</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</main>
<section id="order">
  <div id="container">
    <header>
      <h2>Orders #34562</h2>
      <div id="selector">
        <button class="active">Dine in</button>
        <button>To Go</button>
        <button>Delivery</button>
      </div>
      <div id="description">
        <p>Item</p>
        <p>Qty</p>
        <p>Price</p>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="basket">


    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
      <div id="total">
        <div id="discount">
          <p>Discount</p>
          <p>$0</p>
        </div>
        <div id="subTotal">
          <p>Sub total</p>
          <p class="subTotal">$ 0</p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't have time to go through the full code, but I had an observation. `document.getElementsByClassName('subTotal')[0].innerText = '$ ' + total;`, is the `getElementsByClassName('subTotal')` returning a element or just returning `undefined`? Because, you can't access `innerHTML` from undefined.

Also, is `shopItem.getElementsByClassName('foodImg')[0]` not undefined? If it is undefined, then you will get `src of undefined` error. Is there an element with class name `foodImg`?